# make an absolute div be positioned off screen with scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, absolute

I have an absolutely placed div which uses the CSS as such:

```
.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  margin:0.5%;
  z-index:100;
}
.topRightOverlay {
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
```

My body and HTML both have a min-height and width. However when I reduce the browser window to below the min size, the absolute div does not stick to the far top right, instead it follows the viewport in and then stays positioned as I scroll (not following the viewport back).

How can I ensure this div stays suck to the top right of the HTML/body, even if that means being off screen until scrolled to?

Here is the HTML Structure:

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <form runat="server">
      <div class="overlay topRightOverlay">
        <!-- overlay content -->
      </div>
      <!-- content placeholder for content pages -->
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the HTML, Body CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:600px;
    min-width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
html {overflow:auto;}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 600px;
  min-width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
html {
  overflow: auto;
}
form {
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0.5%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.topRightOverlay {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <form runat="server">
    <div class="overlay topRightOverlay nonInteractive">
      This is an overlay
    </div>
    <!-- content placeholder for content pages -->
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the html structure you are using to this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

You have to give body `position: relative` and add some javascript to keep the `offset()` of the `absolute` element.

Have a look yourself

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var posY;
document.onscroll = function(){
 posY = 100 + $(window).scrollTop();//locate needed Y position 
 $("#absDiv").offset({top: posY}); //Apply position
};
})
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

section {
  height: 1500px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}

#absDiv {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 17px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:100px;
  background-color: #d35400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="absDiv">
      I'm pretty fixed to this place...
    </div>
    <section>
    </section>
</body>
```

Hope I got you right and helped :)

Cheers,

Evoc

Answer (score 0):

use absolute position with .topRightOverlay class .
hope will solve the problem

Comment: I give the floating div both those classes. I separated it out to avoid duplication. I have topLeftOverlay, bottomRightOverlay etc etc